# Fill empty space in table rows with characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I would like to append certain characters to an HTML table row using jQuery, so that each row fills a certain pixel count. I would like to be able to right-align or center-align columns as well. For example:

```
Header        Header2     Header3
something.......foo...........baz
another........abcde.........html
```

Comment: what are these certain characters?

Comment: Probably a period, like in the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a repeating background image on the `<td>` tag and then wrap the text contents in a `<span>` and set the background color of those `<span>` tags to match whatever is behind it.

**See working demo at jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/gDtYz/1/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><span>something</span></td>
      <td><span>foo</span></td>
      <td><span>baz</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><span>another</span></td>
      <td><span>abcde</span></td>
      <td><span>html</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 350px;
    background: #fff; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

th { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; }
td {
    background: transparent 
                url("http://nontalk.s3.amazonaws.com/dots.png") 
                repeat-x 0 75%; 
    height: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}

td span {
    background: #fff; 
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child { text-align: left; }

td:first-child span { padding: 0 4px 0 0; }

th:last-child,
td:last-child { text-align: right; }

td:last-child span { padding: 0 0 0 4px; }
```